# What is the most valuable scripting language, VBScript or JScript?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, javascript

What is the most valuable scripting language, **VBScript** or **JScript**?

Comment: People still use VBScript? ;-)

Comment: Might be an answerable question if you asked about specific metrics, such as compatibility or performance.

Comment: @Briani Driscoll: I was wondering what sort of people think of themselves as using "JScript" (as opposed to Javascript).

Comment: Can you explain why you've limited the choice to VBScript and JScript? I encountered this exact question when first learning classic ASP, and I really hope you're not in that boat in 2010!

Comment: Automation are needed in many applications in an large heterogeneous network of systems... Majority of servers are windows, some are old versions, the install of Powershell must be authorized to each server, bureaucracy is an issue. Strategy being evaluated is to use the "least common denominator" at least to windows servers scripting...

Comment: When simple command line scripts are the rule and error handling is a mirage... VBScript or JScript error handling skills seems to be an evolution... Thank you all for your replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VBScript for working with QTP (QuickTestPro).  For extra 'meat', I can call C# dlls from within VBScript, so I don't really have any limitations (from QTP test automation perspective).  In my circles, I don't hear much about JScript.

Comment: FWIW, I regularly work with JScript and assemblies created in C#/VB.net.

Comment: In my analysis error handling seems to be much better in JScript.

Comment: Error handling in QTP with vbscript is a bit ugly.  Unfortunately I am stuck with vbscript when working with QTP.  This was part of my motivation to move a lot of the processing to a c# dll.  I am now curious about JScript, so I will be taking a look ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on

- Target platform
- Language features
- Personal preference/existing knowledge

Check out what MSDN says about differences to see when to use which of the two:

> **[Clinick's Clinic on Scripting #1: VBScript or JScript?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974627.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks. Thousands of installed windows platforms ranging from windows NT to windows server 2008.

Comment: many do not touch is working cases... but then new automation is an objective...